# Eclipse-Maven Complex Project Dependency (ApacheJena)

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jena

I'm fairly new to the Eclipse and Maven2 worlds.  I'm struggling to comprehend how to add a Maven project dependency on Apache Jena in a simple way.  Specifically, I'd like to add a dependency such as

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
  <artifactId>jena</artifactId>
  <version>${jena.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

And this would automatically pull in the modules(eg. `jena-arq`, `jena-core`, etc).  However, adding this dependency results in a `Missing artifact org.apache.jena:jena:jar:2.11.1` error.  If I add `<type>pom</type>` to the `dependency` the error is gone but I do not get the jars in my project.

In any event, as I understand it, POM is more suited to project <--modules dependencies and what I'm really looking for is project --> lib archive dependencies.

How do I establish such a relationship?  I considered simply replicating the dependency for each module in Jena since it's using a property anyway.  However, it is possible, and Jena is a prime example, that not all modules in a project share the same version.  For example `jena-core` is on 2.11.1 where `jena-tdb` is on 1.0.1 however jena-2.11.1 encompasses `jena-tdb`.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://jena.apache.org/download/maven.html for details.

In brief:

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.jena</groupId>
    <artifactId>apache-jena-libs</artifactId>
    <type>pom</type>
    <version>2.11.1</version> <!-- Set version -->
  </dependency>
```

Note that it is type pom.

Comment: Thanks @Andys, this takes care of the jena artifacts at least. 

I'll be using HBase and Hadoop as well.  Unfortunately I have not found a comparable package, however I have found suggestions to simply reference the most "connected" aka the "client" lib for these packages to have the additional dependencies pulled down implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

there is not a easy way do this.
you must define every dependency jar with special version.